# Php change css class inside foreach

Tags: php, html, arrays, time, foreach

I built a webapp which checks the content of a folder (watchfolder),
now I am trying to color the `<tr></tr>` elements based on their creation time, like if the folder was created a minute ago the tr element should be yellow and so on...

Code looks like this:

```
<?php

$currentTimeFormat = date("d.m.Y H:i",$currentTime);

echo "current time " . $currentTimeFormat;

if (count($watchFolder) > 0) {

    echo '<table class=\'table table-reponsive table-bordered\'>';

        echo '<tbody>';

        foreach ($watchFolder as $key => $value) {

            $currentWatchPath = $watchFolderPath . $key;

            if(strtotime($currentWatchPath) < strtotime('-1 minute')) {
                $class = "redtest";
            }
            if(strtotime($currentWatchPath) < strtotime('-1 hour')) {
                $class = "bluetest";
            }
            if(strtotime($currentWatchPath) < strtotime('-1 day')) { # Older than one day
                $class = "greentest";
            }

            echo '<thead class=\'thead-inverse\'>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope=\'row\' class='.$class.'>'.$key.'&nbsp;|&nbsp;Last change '.date("d.m.Y H:i", filemtime($currentWatchPath)).'</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>';

            foreach ($value as $key => $valueSub) {

                $currentWatchPath2 = $currentWatchPath . '\\' . $key;

                echo '<tr>
                        <td class=\'grey\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key.'&nbsp;|&nbsp;Last change '.date("d.m.Y H:i", filemtime($currentWatchPath2)).'</td>
                      </tr>';

                foreach ($valueSub as $content) {

                    $currentWatchPath3 = $currentWatchPath2 . '\\' . $content;

                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$content.'&nbsp;|&nbsp;Last change '.date("d.m.Y H:i", filemtime($currentWatchPath3)).'</td>
                          </tr>';

                }

            }

        }

        echo '</tbody>';

    echo '</table>';

}
?>
```

$watchfolder is an array which holds all folder of a specific path.

I get the watchfolders (and subfolders) and their time, that works.

But coloring the tr elements based on the creation times of each folder does not work properly, in my case all tr elements are colored green even if I create a new folder it is been colored green whereas it should be red.

Some advice would be cool.

Thus if you think you can improve my code you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because

```
strtotime($currentWatchPath)
```

returns false in your case, because you are giving a filepath as an argument, not a 'datetime' or something like that.

And the last if statement

```
if(strtotime($currentWatchPath) < strtotime('-1 day'))
```

will always be true, so your class will always be green.

Take a look at filemtime($currentWatchPath) or something like instead of strtotime()